# Should I POST high-rate user actions to my server on a per-action basis or send the batch of events once the session is closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, concurrency, redis

I'm building a site where users can watch a video and click as many times as they want to "like" it. It's a bit like Periscope's "Hearts" function for those who know it.

The viewers are viewing the video on a web browser for now. Every "Like" is input into a heroku-hosted REDIS instance, so the write/read are fairly cheap. However potentially there could be a high rate of simultaneous input as many users watch a video at the same time.

In this scenario, I'm facing two options:

1. Send an event to the REDIS instance every time the user "likes." convenience: story the "like" right away with all relevant information. Inconvenience: lots of concurrent likes into the server.
2. Cache the "likes" locally and only send to REDIS once the session is over. Problem: at any time the user can close his browser (and potentially never return) so the "like" information could be lost permanently.

Any advice on which option is preferable?

Comment: Don't cache. Redis increment is probably as fast or faster than your cache.  I bet your concern is rails only, not redis.  You may eventually want to make another endpoint - maybe a simple sinatra app - to simply handle likes.

Comment: Hey thanks @Swards. Why not put this down as an answer? Happy to give points when well-deserved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cache.

First, it's a really big complication as you won't know when the session is really over.

Second, Redis increment is probably as fast or faster than your cache. I bet your concern is Rails only, not Redis.

You may eventually want to make another endpoint - maybe a simple Sinatra app - to simply handle likes.  I noticed autosuggest gems sometimes do this ([for example](https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate)) and it saves all the overhead of a rails request.

If it is a successful app, the concern could be someone writing a script to 'like' continually.  You may need to put in some throttle to allow a limited number of requests over time.